# Google Analytics shows real time visitors but reflects 0 visitors historically

Tags: google-analytics

In my Google Analytics account, I can see data (like pageviews, visitors) in my real time stream, but all of the non-real time data (Standard Reporting) shows 0 pageviews, 0 visitors ever.

Has anyone else had this problem or know of a possible issue/solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any profile filters?

Comment: Make sure uBlock and Ghostery are disabled. I was blocking my own analytics tracker, oops!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Data in Standard Reporting can take up to 24 hours to display.

> According to Google, site statistics update every 24 hours, but the company doesn't specifically state how long it takes to update other information that may be associated with your Google Analytics account. For example, you may also be using Google's AdWords to purchase text-based advertising on other sites. Professionals such as Internet marketing consultant Talal Melhem suggest that traffic data updates every three to four hours, AdWords can take up to 24 hours and E-commerce data in your Google Analytics dashboard lags further behind at up to 72 hours. -- Source: [How Frequently Does Google Analytics Update?](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/frequently-google-analytics-update-33562.html)

Also, check your [Profile Filters](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033162) to make sure you're not excluding traffic per @Eduardo.

Comment: Friendly comment bump to say that the default date view in GA is also set to "last 30 days up to yesterday" -- might need to update the dropdown in top right to see today's information.

Answer (score 1):

There can be a number of reasons for this.

I'm actually investigating a case right now, probably down to the use of GA for analysing application usage. I am seeing real time traffic, but a much reduced traffic set is stored historically.

So far I have:

- Changed User-Agent to something custom
- Removed the domain from the referral exclusion list
- Changed all requests to plain Page Views without customisation of (e.g.) source, medium and the like

Not worked it out yet, will update this when I do!

Answer (score 1):

As @TomFuertes said in comment the 'Users Graph' at google analytics dashboard shows the users of last 7 days from yesterday by default. So if you started tracking your website from today you will surely see active users by the graph will show 0 users. Just choose today from the time range drop-down to see number of users who visited your website today.