# iOS Google Analytics - This report has been filtered

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I'm currently trying to integrate `Google Analytics` version 3 into my iOS app. I'm getting results in the `Real Time` section whenever I'm using the app, but I'm not get any information on the `Overview` section. I'm noticing this message on the `Overview` section:

> This report has been filtered to include only data where there are values for "Mobile Device Branding" dimension.

Is this the reason I'm not getting any info on the `Overview` section? If so, how do I turn off the filter that's only allowing stuff for where there are values for the "Mobile Device Branding" dimension?

Answer (score 0):

It can take up to 24 hours for data to be added to the full report.

See related question and answer here: [Google Analytics shows real time visitors but reflects 0 visitors historically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965646/google-analytics-shows-real-time-visitors-but-reflects-0-visitors-historically)